# how to hide directory and unwanted text in the integrated terminal in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

As you can see, I just want the output without the directory and unwanted text, it is so messy.
I tried to configure the extension `code-runner`, but it doesn't work. And I use it to run c/c++, I didn't try other languages. But I am not sure whether I need to configure `code-runner` extension. And I use the integrated terminal to display the output not the default one.

[image]